# Devolver el objeto cuya propiedad 'nombre' coincida con la cadena 'nombre' recibida por argumento

Tags: javascript, object

La función llamada `buscarAmigo` recibe como argumento un `array` llamado `amigos` que contiene en cada posición del arreglo un objeto que tiene como propiedades 'nombre' y 'edad'. También recibe un `string` llamado `nombre`.

Debe devolver el objeto cuya propiedad 'nombre' coincida con el `string` `nombre` recibido por argumento.

Ej:

```js
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];
buscarAmigo(amigos, 'toni'); // debe devolver { nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 }
```

Intenté la siguiente forma

```js
console.log (nombre.toni),
console.log (edad.33)
```

Pero el ejercicio me sigue saliendo error.

Comment: Qué error te da? Añade el código de lo que has intentado. Te recomiendo que leas el [tour] de bienvenida

Answer (score 3):

Ninguna de estas formas que pruebas funciona porque en ambos casos tratas de acceder a un atributo de objetos que no están definidos, puesto que no tienes ninguna variable con nombre 'nombre' ni 'edad'. Además en el caso de edad estarías tratando acceder a un atributo llamado '33', y eso no está permitido (No puedes tener variables cuyo nombre comience con un número)

```
 console.log (nombre.toni), // Trata de acceder al atributo 'toni' del objeto 'nombre'
 console.log (edad.33),     // Trata de acceder al atributo '33' del objeto 'edad'
```

Para resolver este problema, necesitas emplear un [algoritmo de búsqueda](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_b%C3%BAsqueda). En este caso lo mas sencillo es iterar la lista de amigos y parar cuando el nombre del amigo sea 'toni'. Como te pide una función, debería ser algo así

```js
var amigos = [{nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

function buscarAmigo(amigos, nombre) {
  var i = 0;
  // Mientras queden elementos por comprobar en el array y el nombre del elemento actual no sea el nombre que buscamos, pasamos al elemento siguiente
  while (i < amigos.length && amigos[i].nombre != nombre) {
    i++;
  }
  // Si el motivo por el que se ha salido del array es porque no quedan elementos por comprobar devolver null (no se ha encontrado). En caso contrario devolver el elemento en la posición i (posición en la que se ha encontrado ele lemento)
  if (i < amigos.length) {
    return amigos[i];
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}

console.log(buscarAmigo(amigos, 'toni'));       // Devuelve {nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 }
console.log(buscarAmigo(amigos, 'marta'));      // Devuelve null (no encontrado)
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://jsfiddle.net/b1apzjsn/)

Comment: Puedes usar el Snippet de [es.so], para ejecutar tu código de Javascript, no necesitas un enlace externo en este caso. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

```js
var amigos = [{ nombre: 'toni', edad: 33 } , { nombre: 'Emi', edad: 25 }];

function buscar(nombre)
{
    for (let i = 0; i < amigos.length; i++) {
        if (nombre === amigos[i].nombre) {
          return amigos[i];
        }
    }
    return null;
}

console.log(buscar("toni"));
console.log(buscar("Emi"));
console.log(buscar("Pedro"));
```

Comment: Por favor, lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Pulsa en [edit] y 1. explica brevemente el funcionamiento del código, 2. dale el formato correspondiente, agregando triples acentos graves (o _backticks_, ```) una línea antes y una después del código.